# How to get difference of 2 dates in Toad Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, toad

I'm trying to get the difference between a due date and the system date in Teradata SQL using Toad.

```
SELECT
RECORD_ID,
DUE_DATE,
(DUE_DATE - CURRENT_DATE) DaysDiff

FROM TABLENAME
```

It returns an error:
"Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval."

Comment: What's the data type of DUE_DATE? Apparently it's not a `DATE`

Comment: DUE_DATE is TIMESTAMP(6), YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS.S(6)

Comment: `cast(due_date as date) - current_date`.  As the error says, you cannot compare a timestamp and a date.